# Remove all alphanumeric words from a string in java

Tags: regex

How to find a regular expression to remove all alphanumeric words from a string ?

Here is what i have tried unsuccessfully:

assume my string is:  `String mystring ="the food  was thrill4 not2 that good 6son";`

```
    mystring = mystring.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]","");
```

but its not working.

The expected results should be:
"the food was that good"

Comment: I don't understand the question. `the` is an alphanumeric word, why shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: It sounds like what you want to remove is all words that contain numbers.

Comment: correct. and the number can be anywhere in the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\w*\d+\w*\s*
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OK3exJ/4)

Details:

- `\w*` - starting with 0 or more word chars
- `\d+` - one or more digit
- `\w*` - ends with 0 or more word chars
- `\s*` - match zero or more spaces after the word

Comment: \w*\d+\w*\s this seems to be what i want, thanks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is operating at the character level, not on words. Use `\b` to match word boundaries, and then match what's between them.

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\b([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)\\b", "");
```